# Eclipse : Opened workspace by date

Tags: eclipse

I wonder if there is any trick to know which workspace was opened in a specific date with Eclipse.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you modify a file in Eclipse, a copy of the old contents is kept in the local history. At any time, you can compare or replace a file with any older version from the history. Although this is no replacement for a real code repository, it can help you out when you change or delete a file by accident.

The path of the history folder inside your workspace is

```
 .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/
```

Here's a simple example. Lets assume that you lost your file on Jun 12

```
 cd .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/
 ls -al * | grep "Jun 22" | grep "r\-\-" | sort -k 6
 -rw-r--r--    1 myusername  myusername  41318 Jun 22 11:06 30ec989295bc00111703c0e5cbee369d
 -rw-r--r--    1 myusername  myusername    865 Jun 22 12:40 b015c947a2bc00111703c0e5cbee369d
 -rw-r--r--    1 myusername  myusername    865 Jun 22 12:40 e090e72da2bc00111703c0e5cbee369d
 -rw-r--r--    1 myusername  myusername    865 Jun 22 12:41 00e4ff56a2bc00111703c0e5cbee369d
 -rw-r--r--    1 myusername  myusername    872 Jun 22 12:42 7098a672a2bc00111703c0e5cbee369d
 -rw-r--r--    1 myusername  myusername  26100 Jun 22 13:19 4076ddc9a7bc00111703c0e5cbee369d
 -rw-r--r--    1 myusername  myusername  26066 Jun 22 13:21 106bb9d3a7bc00111703c0e5cbee369d
 -rw-r--r--    1 myusername  myusername  26066 Jun 22 13:21 b0895feca7bc00111703c0e5cbee369d
```

For more detail you can refer the [eclipse FAQ Link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_is_the_workspace_local_history_stored%3F)